# How to put a number of timedate data into a subset of dataframe while keeping the data type?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which has name as the index while a column of birth date e.g

```
> df_birthdate
         date
Paul     2009-03-07  
Peter    2000-06-23  
Pauline  2001-03-03  
Paula    2002-02-17

> type(df_birthdate.date[0])
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

> df_huge = pd.DataFrame({'School': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})
> df_huge['new_date'] = ''
> idx_t = df_huge.School == 'A'
```

And I have a huge dataframe called df_huge which I want to put the date into it.  I know that the order won't change.

`df_huge.loc[idx_t, "new_date"] = df_birthdate.values`

The above code works for me in the most cases, however, when the 'date' column is in datetime format, by applying .values, the data which I put into the df_huge dataframe are no longer in datetime format.  Any suggestion to put 'date' from df_birthdate into a specific location of the df_huge?  Many thanks.

Comment: Can you add sample of `df_huge` ? also maybe help `df_birthdate.to_numpy()`

Comment: @jezrael I've added a sample of df_huge.  .to_numpy() yielded the same result as .values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit `df_huge['new_date'] = ''` for assign empty strings to column:

```
idx_t = df_huge.School == 'A'
df_huge.loc[idx_t, "new_date"] = df_birthdate.to_numpy()
print (df_huge)
  School   new_date
0      A 2009-03-07
1      A 2000-06-23
2      A 2001-03-03
3      A 2002-02-17
4      B        NaT
5      B        NaT
6      B        NaT
7      B        NaT

print (df_huge.dtypes)
School              object
new_date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```